# How to install boto3 on AWS EMR?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda

I am running Jupiter notebook
I can not work without boto3.

```
!conda install --yes boto3
```

Got

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -
```

My conda

```
!type -a conda
conda is /opt/conda/bin/conda
```

If

```
!conda install --yes --prefix {sys.prefix} boto3
```

got

```
EnvironmentLocationNotFound: Not a conda environment: /home/notebook/work/{sys.prefix}

! grep -v '^\s*\(#.*\)\?$' ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
grep: /home/notebook/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py: No such file or directory
```

This is what `! conda list` shows

```
# packages in environment at /opt/conda:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                 conda_forge    conda-forge
_openmp_mutex             4.5                       0_gnu    conda-forge
anaconda-client           1.7.2                      py_0    conda-forge
anaconda-navigator        1.9.12                   py37_1    defaults
attrs                     19.3.0                     py_0    conda-forge
autovizwidget             0.13.1                     py_0    defaults
awseditorssparkmonitoringwidget 1.0                      py37_0    file:///tmp/conda-repo
awseditorsstorage         0.0.1                    py37_0    file:///tmp/conda-repo
backcall                  0.1.0                    py37_0    defaults
beautifulsoup4            4.9.0            py37hc8dfbb8_0    conda-forge
blas                      1.0                         mkl    defaults
bleach                    3.1.4                      py_0    defaults
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py37h8f50634_1000    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.8                h516909a_2    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2020.1.1                      0    defaults
certifi                   2020.4.5.1               py37_0    defaults
cffi                      1.14.0           py37hd463f26_0    conda-forge
chardet                   3.0.4           py37hc8dfbb8_1006    conda-forge
click                     7.1.2              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
clyent                    1.2.2                      py_1    conda-forge
colorama                  0.4.3                      py_0    defaults
conda                     4.8.3            py37hc8dfbb8_1    conda-forge
conda-build               3.19.2           py37hc8dfbb8_0    conda-forge
conda-env                 2.6.0                         1    conda-forge
conda-package-handling    1.6.0            py37h8f50634_2    conda-forge
conda-verify              3.1.1           py37hc8dfbb8_1001    conda-forge
cryptography              2.9.2            py37hb09aad4_0    conda-forge
cycler                    0.10.0                   py37_0    defaults
dbus                      1.13.6               he372182_0    conda-forge
decorator                 4.4.2                      py_0    conda-forge
defusedxml                0.6.0                      py_0    defaults
entrypoints               0.3                      py37_0    defaults
expat                     2.2.9                he1b5a44_2    conda-forge
filelock                  3.0.10                     py_0    conda-forge
fontconfig                2.13.1            h86ecdb6_1001    conda-forge
freetype                  2.10.1               he06d7ca_0    conda-forge
future                    0.18.2           py37hc8dfbb8_1    conda-forge
gettext                   0.19.8.1          hc5be6a0_1002    conda-forge
gitdb                     4.0.2                      py_0    defaults
gitpython                 3.1.1                      py_1    defaults
glib                      2.64.2               h6f030ca_0    conda-forge
glob2                     0.7                        py_0    conda-forge
gmp                       6.1.2                h6c8ec71_1    defaults
gst-plugins-base          1.14.5               h0935bb2_2    conda-forge
gstreamer                 1.14.5               h36ae1b5_2    conda-forge
hdijupyterutils           0.12.9                     py_0    defaults
icu                       64.2                 he1b5a44_1    conda-forge
idna                      2.9                        py_1    conda-forge
importlib-metadata        1.6.0            py37hc8dfbb8_0    conda-forge
importlib_metadata        1.6.0
```

Do multiple channels play the role?

How my install command should look like?

Comment: Can you confirm if you are able to reach internet via EMR cluster? Did you launched in private subnet and if not security groups are not blocking internet?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy Will check this out.

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy Outbound rules?

Comment: are you able to ping google.com ?

Comment: I am in public subnet(my EC2 instances.)

Comment: ping google.com PING www.google.com (74.125.193.106) 56(84) bytes of data.

Comment: Are you using pyspark as kernel in your notebook?

Comment: No,this one is Python3.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218347/discussion-between-prabhakar-reddy-and-mikibelavista).